ld and gcc fails to link glibc for assembly code
I am trying to compile an assembly program that calls upon C functions. As a test I am making a terrible hello world calling printf from stdio.h. The C version should look something like
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

According to this to call printf the code should look like this: (note I am using nasm, not as)
extern printf

section .data
msg db "Hello, world!", 0xa, 0x0

section .text
global _start
_start:
    push word msg
    call printf
    add rsp, 8

    mov eax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall

nasm -f elf64 -o a.o a.asm has no issue assmebling, however when it comes to linking I am having some issues.
First I tried with ld, because that is what I normally use with assmebly, ld -o a a.o -lc returns 1 and says
a.o: in function `_start':
a.asm:(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against `.data'

I don't know what this means but many people online were saying to link with gcc, so I just tried gcc -o a a.o but that also failed saying
/usr/bin/ld: a.o: in function `_start':
a.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: a.o: relocation R_X86_64_16 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This complains that there are multiple entry points and it doesn't know from where to start, so I tried renaming _start to main to match what you normally see in C, but that doesn't remove all of the errors
/usr/bin/ld: a.o: relocation R_X86_64_16 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Just to test I tried to create the C code and assemble it with gcc -o a.o -c a.c then link with ld ld -o a a.o -lc which once again throws a cryptic error
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401020

But it links anyways because it is only a warning, however running the program causes bash to throw an error
bash: ./a: cannot execute: required file not found

How do I link libc and other external libraries, such as opengl, if my code is in assmebly?

This has nothing to do with libraries; the push word msg is just very wrong.  It is asking for the address of msg to be truncated to 16 bits before being pushed onto the stack, which is nonsensical and the linker doesn't support it.  But with x86-64, arguments are not passed on the stack to begin with.  I think you need to start over with an assembly tutorial that is actually written for x86-64 on Linux.

For 64-bit code you would do lea rdi, [rel msg] before call print, and omit the add rsp, 8.  Then your original nasm and ld commands would work.

It's dicey to try to call printf or other C library functions from a program that begins with _start instead of main and thus does not run the C library's startup code.  But on Linux/glibc, it seems to work in practice, at least for simple example programs, so it's probably okay for getting started.  Just don't get attached to it.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has some possible resources you could look at.  Pay careful attention to the "bitness" (16/32/64), assembler, and OS that each one is written for.  As  a beginner, you don't want to get involved in trying to translate between them.

@NateEldredge running my original ld command creates the same bash error (required file not found)
i thought word meant the number of bits the program is aligned to (so 16 bits for a 16 bit program)
